# ex35.py Learning Python the Hard Way

Tags: python-2.7

I'm working my way through Learn Python the Hard Way and I've run into a snag that I can't find answered elsewhere.

As far as I can see I've typed line 7 properly yet I keep getting a syntax error.

```
next = raw_input(("> ")
if "0" in next or "1" in next:
    how_much = int(next)
else:
    dead("Man, learn to type a number.")
```

This is the error warning:

File "ex35.py", line 7
    if "0" in next or "1" in next:
                                 ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Where the caret is directly underneath the colon, as if that is the problem but if statements need to end in a colon so I'm puzzled.

I even deleted and retyped the lines in case and still nothing. I can't get past it.

Comment: Count your parentheses in the `next` line.  Voting to close as typo.

Comment: That line with the extra parenthesis is line 6.
Because it flagged line 7 as having the syntax error and placed the caret under the colon I just didn't see it.
I'll have to look out for this in future.